# || and onmessage in javascript

Tags: javascript, appjs

I am reading a open source project and it has a [js file](https://github.com/appjs/appjs/blob/master/lib/bridge.js) like this

```
var pipe = function(source, listeners){
    source.onmessage = function onmessage(msg){
           //.. do something ..
    };

    return {
      //.. something ...
    };
  }(nativeWindow || appjs, {});
```

What does `(nativeWindow || appjs )` means where they both are objects ?

Does it mean that this function is called for both of them ?

Or it is merging both of these objects ?

And is this `.onmessage` is something standard thing like `alert()` or `window` ? What i mean by standard is that is there something happening behind the scenes in this `.onmessage` function or is it just like simple function ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: This might be easy for others but for somebody with c++ background who is trying to understand a javascript file, it seems confusing.

Comment: Thanks you all. can you have a look at http://help.dottoro.com/ljjqtjsj.php and tell your final comments on this question.

Comment: But you're asking about 4 different questions here.  Your question seems to be 'talk me through this JavaScript'

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks but i wanted to know that where i should search about this onmessage event firing in the framwork if its their thing or if its something like addEventListener like standard thing then i would not be able to view whats happening in their code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if nativeWindow evaluates to false (e.g. if it's undefined) then appjs is passed in as source; otherwise nativeWindow is passed in as source. The property onmessage  of whichever object ispassed in as source is then set to the onmessage function

Comment: so onmessage is simple function, nothing like some standard function that would be invoked if something happens on dom ?

Comment: No, it's not a simple function, please read about [Post Messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage)

Comment: so that must be framework thing not of any standard thing of browsers. can you have a look at http://help.dottoro.com/ljjqtjsj.php and tell your final comments on this question.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI `onmessage` is very standard property, no frameworks needed to use it.

Answer (score 2):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) :

> expr1 || expr2
>
> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either
>   operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

In this specific case, the first value whose value is defined is passed as argument.

Comment: can you comment about the onmessage thing too ?

Comment: *In this specific case, the first value whose value is defined is passed as argument.* isn't strictly true. It's the first value that is truthy, or the last value if all values are falsey.

Comment: @PaulGrime "In this specific case" : I commented on this use case, not on the general working of ||.

Answer (score 2):

`.onmessage`is whatever it is assigned in the `pipe` function. It is just a normal property on the `source` object.

The `||` and `&&` in javascript returns a value.
This means; `nativeWindow` OR `appjs` gets passed in, as the returned value from the expression; the last evaluated expression gets returned. If `nativeWindow`is a falsy (null, undefined etc) value, appjs gets passed in. If `nativeWindow` is thruthy (e.g. an object) it gets passed in. Just think `this OR that`. If both values are falsy, the one on the right hand side will still be passed in. Read more on || and && here: http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510

Answer (score 1):

`||` is the `OR` operator. It also short-circuits if the left-hand evaluates is true-ish. So what it does is provide the function with either the value of `nativeWindow` OR `appjs` if `nativeWindow` is false-ish.

A more verbose of the same would be:

```
var pipe = function()...;
if(nativeWindow) {
    pipe = pipe(nativeWindow);
} else {
    pip = pipe(appjs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(nativeWindow || appjs, {}) = (source, listeners)
```

They are the parameters passed

```
nativeWindow  || appjs
```

means if *nativeWindow* is undefined or falsy take the value of *appjs*

```
source.onmessage
```

*onmessage* is the property of the object *source* (passed as `nativeWindow || appjs`) which holds a function in your case

Comment: Great answer! succinct and complete.